Unable to Resolve Firebase Dependency in Expo Snack: "Failed to resolve dependency 'firebase@10.12.1'"
I'm developing a React Native app using Expo's Snack, and I'm encountering issues with resolving the Firebase dependency. Here’s what I've done so far:
Problem:
I receive the following error when trying to use Firebase in my Snack project:
Failed to resolve dependency 'firebase@10.12.1' (Network request failed)
error
even i have changed versions, 8.0.0 was fine but It again gave such errors
with 8.0.0
Updated package.json:
I tried using the latest Firebase version as well as an older, more stable version.
{
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~48.0.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.4",
    "firebase": "9.6.1",  // Also tried with firebase@10.12.1
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.18.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "~17.0.21",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.64.12",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  }
}

Initialized Firebase in firebaseConfig.js:
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: ""
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);

export { db };

Firebase Version Tried: 10.12.1 ,8.0.0 and 9.6.1
Environment: Expo Snack
Error Message: Failed to resolve dependency 'firebase@10.12.1' (Network request failed)

I also have the same problem. The paleactive form I was able to solve was through the downgrade of the Firebase version to 8.10.0 on Package.json
package.json
 "Dependences": {
 "Firebase": "8.10.0",

Follow the link with my example.
https://snack.expo.dev/@jacksonm/aula-react-native-twitter-2023-2

use "Firebase": "8.0.0",

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Please, [edit] and try for [answer], describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem, make the additional insight more obvious which you contribute beyond existing answers, the relevant advantage which your solution achieves, especially if the difference is so small and non-obvious. Consider taking the [tour].
